# ¿Por qué el significado de resabio se asocia con malas costumbres?

Tags: etimología, significado

En el DLE se puede ver que en las acepciones de [resabio](https://dle.rae.es/resabio) actualmente se tiene como primera definición:

> 1. m. Vicio o mala costumbre que se toma o adquiere.

Según el mapa de diccionarios esta fue la 2da definición hasta la edición de 2001, aunque (en mi ignorancia) la palabra suele usarse con esta definición habitualmente, a diferencia de la que actualmente está en tercer lugar y estuvo unos 3 siglos en primer lugar (de forma similar)

> Sabor desagradable que deja algo.

Desde la etimología, es más cercano al término latino *resapĕre* 'tener sabor', 'saber a'. Pero entonces, ¿Cómo surge la primera acepción actual?.

Comment: Siempre asocié *resabio* a una mala costumbre que viene de antiguo, nunca he visto empleada la palabra simplemente como "vicio" sino como un concepto parecido al de *rémora*. Es decir que en el uso que yo conozco *resabio* es una cosa pero hay un recuerdo de que significaba otra, y esta conexión no aparece en la def. 1 del DLE...

Comment: El significado que yo siempre le he dado es que dice la  DRAE:  Dicho de una persona o de un animal: Que, por su experiencia vital, ha perdido su ingenuidad volviéndose desconfiado o desabrido. Ejemplo: al toro resabiado no le engañas con un capote, y sabe que tiene que embestir al torero.  Es decir, no es que se haya convertido en un toro «sabio», sino  en uno  «re-sabio».

Comment: @Fran haces mención al segundo significado que le da el DLE (ten en cuenta que busco resabio y no resabiado)

Comment: @VeAqui Pero más allá que uno es sustantivo y el otro odjetivo, se refieren a lo mismo.  El toro está  resabiado porque tienen un resabio, que es el vicio o mala costumbre de no embestir al capote (mala costumbre según el torero, claro está, para el toro sin duda es una virtud)